# Parsing date - yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss

Tags: java, datetime

I have a date string which is as follows:

> 2015-12-24 08:06:44

Now I have a parse function:

```
public static String parseDate(String date) {
        Date oldDate = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Unparsed: "+date);
            DateFormat oldFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
            oldDate = oldFormat.parse(date);
            System.out.println("old Date parsed: "+oldDate);
            DateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date result = newFormat.parse(oldDate.toString());

            return result.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The first System.out gives me:

> Unparsed: 2015-12-24 08:06:44

The second one:

> Sat Jan 24 08:06:44 GMT+05:30 2015

Whereas for the second one I have clearly mentioned the date format to be  as:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Please advise on what's wrong here

I only want to get the month and day from the input string - Desired would be `Dec 24` from the above sample date string.

Comment: You're using the wrong format string, basically. You've got minutes twice, and 12-hour format instead of 24-hour format. You want `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. I suggest you read http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/

Comment: This is confusing with such bad naming conventions, although I should have brushed up with the documentation.

Comment: It's not a bad naming convention - it's standard in many places, but yes, it does require you to read the documentation. How did you expect "mm" to mean two different things?

Comment: (The general problem of "I didn't read the docs for SimpleDateFormat" is extremely common here... I'll find a dupe to close this question.)

Comment: I am still getting the output as: `old Date parsed: Thu Dec 24 08:06:44 GMT+05:30 2015`

Comment: So this time it sounds like you haven't read the documentation for `Date.toString`. Hint: a `Date` object doesn't know what format it might have been parsed from.

Comment: Oh My! So much for parsing a date! Going, I am reading up on docs now!

Comment: Lesson: Read doc before you code!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Its `MM` for month not `mm`.

```
DateFormat oldFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
```

[SimpleDateFormat doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I suspect the OP wants to be able to differentiate between 8am and 8pm.

Comment: Except that now doesn't match the input string... (Hint: I'm 99.9% certain the OP wants HH rather than hh.)